# Having problems with the form inside the table in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

form instructions:

1. the table consist of four columns and six rows.
2. the form is embedded inside a table
3. the table consist of two columns and six rows

   - the text and text box in Column 2, Row2 span four rows
   - There are two 
      tags used to separate the text and text box

     ```
     <table>
         <form name="application" method="post" action="">
         <tr>
             <th>Application Form</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>First Name<input name="firstname" type="textbox" size="20"</td><br>
             <td rowspan="4">Countries and places you wish to visit:<br><br>
             <textarea></textarea></td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Last Name:<input type="textbox" size="20"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Phone number:<input type="textbox" size="20"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Email:<input type="textbox" size="20"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <th colspan="4"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
             <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"></th>
         </tr>
         </form>
     ```

     I need to make this table[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud2xC.jpg)

Comment: Hi, @Marland, welcome to SO. what the problem you have met for the above codes? According the codes, you should move out the `<form>` and `</form>` out of `<table>`. And you also need to add a closure tag `</table>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your codes, please check below:

1. Move out the `form` from `table`;
2. Add `</table>`
3. Adjust the `textarea`;

```html
<form name="application" method="post" action="">
  <table cellpadding="10px">
    <tr>
        <th>Application Form</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:<input name="firstname" type="textbox" size="20"</td>
        <td>Countries and places you wish to visit:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name:<input type="textbox" size="20"></td>
        <td rowspan="3" valign="top">
          <textarea></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone number:<input type="textbox" size="20"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:<input type="textbox" size="20"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th colspan="4">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
         <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">
       </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```